# Where do I get resgen.exe to use with NANT?

Tags: .net, nant, windows-server-2003, resgen

I am simply trying to run NANT with resgen, but I can't seem to find what I need to download to have it available in '**C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\bin\resgen.exe**' on my server.

Thank you.

Comment: That requires installing Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On the server running your NANT script, you can either install Visual Studio 2005 to get "resgen.exe" available at the location described in your question or you can install the [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6b6c21d2-2006-4afa-9702-529fa782d63b&displaylang=en).

Once installed, "resgen.exe" will be available at a location similar to:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin

Comment: I can locate the file there, but it closes immediately after displaying some text that I'm not able to read. Is there a way to make it run?

Comment: Open a command prompt in the folder and run it from the command line. Even when you're not dealing with command line tools that expect arguments, this is a good way of diagnosing issues with executables that terminate immediately.

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand why, if VS is such a great product and very well designed, we are still anchored to the past with this user unfriendly tools

Comment: Because we are not supposed to be users. Imagine the nightmare of having to use GUI applications on an automated deploy pipeline...

Answer (score 8):

With **Visual Studio** developer installation "resgen" can be found at

#### Visual Studio 2012

> %PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\resgen.exe

#### Visual Studio 2017

> %PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools\resgen.exe

Answer (score 4):

To obtain all available versions and their respective paths

- In command-line ***`prompt>`***

```
where.exe /r \ ResGen.exe

rem :: results ::

c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\ResGen.exe
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools\ResGen.exe
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7 Tools\ResGen.exe
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.1 Tools\ResGen.exe
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\ResGen.exe
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\ResGen.exe
```

- In ***> Start Menu -> Run***

```
cmd /k where.exe /r \ ResGen.exe

rem :: results ::

c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\ResGen.exe
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools\ResGen.exe
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7 Tools\ResGen.exe
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.1 Tools\ResGen.exe
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\ResGen.exe
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\ResGen.exe
```

- Get all outputs on your ClipBoard add **`| clip`**

```
cmd /k where.exe /r \ ResGen.exe | clip
```